# does anyone have the source code for this Microsoft blog on sharing ASP and .Net session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

I'm trying to finally remove my company from classic ASP and migrate to .Net. We are going to have to do it in stages so we need to temporarily share session between the legacy ASP app and the new .Net app.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

This Microsoft blog post is exactly what we want to implement but there is no source code? The author (who I tried to email, he no longer exists) references demo source code that is provided but its 13 years later and I can't find it. If anyone has this source code or can provide an implementation of it I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I've had some success running an MVC and "old style" Asp.Net web applications running together. Not sure if it will work for you though. I'm on mobile now, I'll explain tomorrow

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to it

Comment: Since you're using classic asp I think my solution will not work for you. John's answer looks promising.

Comment: @DavidLibido - The issue here is that Classic ASP and ASP.net can't read each other's session variables.  The usual hack to get around this is to use hidden pages and invisible iframes to synchronise them, but it means displaying your session variables client side, and I'm guessing that the OP doesn't want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the article on web.archive.org you can find a working download link for the source code. The download is an .exe file because it's a self extracting zip. I'd almost forgotten that zip support wasn't always native to Windows.  Given the age of the article it will probably be using asp.net 1.1, so I can't guarantee you won't encounter compatibility problems

Here's a link to the specific article in the archive:

https://web.archive.org/web/20080508194531/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

And here's the link to download the source code:

https://web.archive.org/web/20080508194531/http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/0/980e634a-f4ba-43a0-9d6d-119ba7e86403/sessionsample.exe

Web Archive is generally a very useful resource if you're looking for scripts you used in the past which have disappeared

Comment: I've never used this before, thank you! I was able to download the original source code, hoping it will help get us out of classic ASP now! Thanks again